# Increment highest numbered subkey

Tags: batch-file

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _key=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExemptDomainFileTypePairsFromFileTypeDownloadWarnings
set _name=1
for /f %%a in ('reg query %_key%') do (
    if %%a GEQ !_name! set /a _name=%%a+1
)
REG ADD %_key% /v %_name% /t REG_SZ /d 0
endlocal
```

How can I increment the highest numbered subkey? (If none exists, the first must be 1.)

Comment: two severe fails in your code: wrong quotes in `for` (it's either `for /f "..." %%a in ('command') do ...` or `for /f "usebackq ..." %%a in (\`command\`) do ...`), and `_name` is undefined in the first run of the loop, causing a syntax error with `if`.

Comment: …and there is a logical error: the comparison operator should be `GEQ` since you already add `1` inside of the loop…

Comment: …and probably a worse error than each of those, as soon as you used `endlocal`, both the values of `%_key%` and `%_name%`, became undefined again, leaving you with the command `REG ADD /v /t REG_SZ /d 0`!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; I have updated the code accordingly. However, I still cannot increment the subkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows is a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, which should:

- create the key with a value of `1` and your data, if no numeric value exists.
- add your data to the value of the first missing number in the sequence.
- add your data to the next number value in the sequence, if none are missing.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "RegVal={"domains": ["*"], "file_extension": "swf"}"
Set "RegKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExemptDomainFileTypePairsFromFileTypeDownloadWarnings"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Val[) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=0"
For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%reg.exe Query "%RegKey%" /T REG_SZ 2^>NUL
 ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /R /C:"[ ][ ]*[1-9][0-9]*[ ][ ]*REG_SZ[ ][ ]*"'
) Do Set /A Val[%%G] = 1, i = %%G 
For /L %%G In (1,1,%i%) Do If Not Defined Val[%%G] (Set "Val[%%G]=1"
) Else Set "Val[%%G]="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ('"(Set Val[) 2>NUL"'
) Do Set /A i = %%G - 1 & GoTo AddVal
:AddVal
Set /A i += 1
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "%RegKey%" /V %i% /D "%RegVal:"=\"%" /F 1>NUL
```

*You would obviously change my example value string `{"domains": ["*"], "file_extension": "swf"}` on line 3, before running the script **elevated**.*

Comment: Thank you; that was more complex than I anticipated, but I am happy that it works!